# How do I get react-stormpath to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers?

Tags: reactjs, stormpath

I'm having a similar problem to:

[401 Error with post request Stormpath Express + React + Node + Gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39198346/401-error-with-post-request-stormpath-express-react-node-gulp)

Specifically, when I try to use the LoginForm or RegisterForm from react-stormpath, I get:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.stormpath.com/v1/applications/[ID]/oauth/token. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

I have added http://localhost:3000 to the Authorized Origin URIs in the Stormpath console, but that doesn't help.  I've inspected the request using Chrome, and indeed, there is no ACAO header coming back.

Unlike the other issue linked to above, I'm not doing anything custom.  My login page just looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { LoginForm } from 'react-stormpath';

export default class Login extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <LoginForm />
    );
  }
}
```

I don't even know how to debug this issue because I don't know what's going on under the hood in react-stormpath.

**Edit: Adding the react-stormpath config:**

```
ReactStormpath.init({
  endpoints: {
    baseUri: 'https://api.stormpath.com/v1/applications/[ID]'
  }
});
```

Comment: Something doesn't look quite right in that request. It should be going to `localhost`, not `api.stormpath.com`. Can you post your react-stormpath configuration (if any)?

Comment: I assume you mean the object passed to the init call.  I've added that above, which I modeled after the quickstart on the react-sdk-stormpath quick start [on github](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-react).

Comment: Ah but that was the clue I needed.  I was supposed to put the "DNS Label" there, not the "HREF".  With that change, it is working.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah, I think you beat me to figuring out the answer. :) My initial comment might be wrong in your case, since you probably do want the Client API URL and not `localhost`. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `ReactStormpath.init`. Your React app can't connect to `api.stormpath.com` directly, because that requires using a secure API key. Your `baseUri` should instead be one of:

- Your Stormpath application's Client API URL, like `https://foo-bar.apps.stormpath.io`. This is a separate API domain that allows untrusted clients (like React) to connect. [This part](https://docs.stormpath.com/client-api/product-guide/latest/client_config.html#react) of the documentation is a better example.
- Your web server, like `http://localhost:3000` - if you are using something like express-stormpath (I can't quite tell from your question)

Disclaimer: I work at Stormpath.

Comment: I'm using the correct Client API URL and I'm having the same problem as the OP. The documentation for the Client API says something about configuring which origins are allowed to access the endpoint, but there are no instructions for how to do so.

Comment: @DanielArant Can you post it as a new question?

Comment: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41994231/why-am-i-receiving-a-cross-origin-error-when-using-the-react-stormpath-loginform

Comment: Neeeever mind. I just found it right where the documentation said it was. Feel free to answer anyway just for  posterity's stake.

That's what staying up late to solve a problem gets you.