# Why am I receiving a cross-origin error when using the react-stormpath LoginForm component?

Tags: reactjs, stormpath

I followed the instructions found in the readme in the [stormapth-sdk-react github respository](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-react#stormpath-react-sdk) to set up a basic login form. The form displays, but I am immediately greeted by errors in the console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://{redacted}.apps.stormpath.io/me. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

I get an identical error for the login endpoint.

The [Client API Guide](https://docs.stormpath.com/client-api/product-guide/latest/configuration.html) indicates that client endpoints have to be configured to allow traffic from a particular domain, but does not provide any instructions for how to do this:

> Applications that use the Client API have two relevant configuration parameters, both found on your Application’s page in the Stormpath Admin Console:...
>
> 1. **Authorized Callback URIs:** This list should include any URIs that your users will be returned to after they have completed authentication with an outside provider, for example as a part of the social login flow. For example, if you do not specify a redirect URI when you kick off the social login flow, the user will be redirected the first URI in this list.
> 2. **Authorized Origin URIs:** **This list should include the application’s URL, or whatever URL will be included in the Origin header of requests sent to the Client API.**

What do I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this, you can login to https://api.stormpath.com, navigate to Applications > My Application, and modify the **Authorized Origin URIs** to include `http://localhost:3000`.

Comment: In my bleary-eyed attempts to get the working last night, I completely overlooked that part of the configuration interface. This question was more about where exactly the Authorized Origin URIs could be found.

Comment: @DanielArant The 'Authorized Origin URIs' field is not populated with anything by default. You need to go to Applications -> Your Application -> Authorized Origin URIs and add your domain there.

Comment: Yep, I figured that out. I just couldn't find the "Authorized Origin URIs" field.

Answer (score 0):

Stormpath seems to use a pretty similar setup to many API services. Like the directions say, go to your Stormpath Admin Console, and put your hostname (http://localhost:3000) in the relevant fields for both 1. and 2.

Doing so tells the Stormpath API to allow data to be sent to your application.

Comment: Yeah, the problem was that I couldn't find where to add that information. After composing this question I went back to my admin portal and found it almost immediately. That's what I get for staying up late to solve an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) mechanism gives web servers cross-domain access controls, which enable secure cross-domain data transfers.

*As the server you are using (for react) differs from the server you are requesting data(node or something else). (even the subdomain or port matters)*

**index.js:** (server)

```
const cors = require('cors');
..
..
app.use(cors());
```

for more info about using cors: [npm cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)